# Process when we work with fork in git

Tags: git, github

Is there any short way by which we can daily update our fork without removing and adding origin?

Currently, working with the latest branch, first we remove our remote URL and add the project's main remote URL, then fetch all the branches and update `master`, and finally put back our own URL to update the forked repository.

Comment: You can (and should) have multiple remotes: the one from where you forked is traditionally named upstream. Yours, to which you push, is traditionally named origin. Fetch from upstream to be up-to-date. https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/, https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/

Comment: so upstream is basically use for updating fork branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git lets you configure multiple remote repositories that you push to and pull from at will (depending on permissions, of course). The remote you cloned from, `origin`, is not special in this regard, it's just the first one.

Start by adding the second remote, pointing at the repository you forked from. As [JB Nizet mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992801/process-when-we-work-with-fork-in-git#comment55741363_33992801), this one is often called `upstream`, but you can call it anything you like. When I have several remotes pointing at GitHub, I typically name them after the user who owns that fork.

```
git remote add upstream <clone url>
```

Now you can work with that remote just like you'd work with `origin`.

```
git fetch origin
git fetch upstream
```

And you can merge branches from either into the branch you'd like to update.

```
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
git push origin master
```

Keep in mind that there's nothing unique about `origin` or about `upstream` - they're just copies of the repository. You probably have write permission only on `origin`, but besides that, anything you're used to doing with `origin`, you can do with any remote by referencing its name instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just have two remotes with the names you choose, which should not necessarily be origin. And no need to remove remotes.